# How to bundle a React app to a subdirectory on a server?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React app I've been developing on my localhost. I want to copy it to a server into a subdirectory called vensa.

My webpack config file looks like this..

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: 'build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|eot|svg|ttf|woff(2)?)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?/,
        loader: 'url'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('vensa-dashboard.css')
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './build'
  }
};
```

The index.html file looks like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vensa Development Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vensa-dashboard.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my routes.js file is...

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import VensaDashboard from './components/VensaDashboard';
import Inbox from './components/Inbox';
import Todo from './components/Todo';
import Home from './components/Home';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={VensaDashboard}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/message" component={Inbox} />
    <Route path="/todo/:todoPage" component={Todo} />
  </Route>
);
```

However, if I do just run `webpack -p` and copy the 3 files over to that subdirectory, it doesn't work as the root path is `/` and it can't find the js and css files. I'm not sure what (the best way) to change in (probably one or all of these 3 files) to get it to work in a subdirectory?

The full source code of the app is [here](https://github.com/magician11/vensa-test) in case that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Almost seems easier to create a subdomain instead for the app so I don't have to play around with the config of the app?!

Comment: Simply add - subdirectory path in homepage: "/subdirectory" inside package.json.
and add a basename in the router if required. ref link - https://www.fullstacktutorials.com/deploy-react-app-subdirectory-10.html

Answer (score 59):

If you are using React Router v4 you should be able to set it using basename={`foobar`}.

```
<Router history={browserHistory} basename={'foobar'}>
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
```

Link to the docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

Note: if using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) in a sub directory you will also want to set `"homepage": "/foobar/",` in your package.json file. So the production build points at the right path.

Comment: this works holy Jesus it works thanks man I searched  this solution for days

Comment: @sparshturkane hey! can you please share a working example of this? I'm also stuck with this.

Comment: @DipenDedania For instance 
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar" />
<Link to="/today" />  .. renders <a href="/calendar/today"> From the docs.

Comment: This works for production, but I'm still searching a solution for development on port :3000, I use a workaround for instance: manually add the inclusion of the bundle with a relative path (the dev build produces a bsolute path to the root) : I added <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bundle.js"></script> to index.html

Comment: Thanks @trenthogan, that is awesome. But as novice I was stumped as where to actually put the code as I was working from a tutorial w/out ROUTER.  Here's what worked... in my index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router basename={' foobar '}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();

Comment: In addition to these answers, I also added the following environment variable to my `.env.production` file so that all the static files were physically built into a subdirectory as well: `BUILD_PATH=./build/foobar`. (I also had an nginx configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74539348/6854489) to help me with routing requests to the subdirectory correctly)

Answer (score 16):

1. Add "homepage": "https://yourdomain/subdirectory/" in package.json
2. Update the Routes, set sub directory in route,

```
<Router basename={'/directory-name'}>
  <Route path='/' component={Home} />
</Router>
```

3. Add base in public/index.html. It helps to set path without issues.

   `<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">`
4. make all css, js, images & all resource loading './assets/your resource.'
5. Only look if you are using history. add basename in history

```
    const historyConfig = {
        basename: 'your subdirectory'
    };
    const history = createBrowserHistory(historyConfig);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using history, No one mention that

Answer (score 10):

In my situation, I needed to support a scenario, where there might be 0 to many subfolders with unknown names and production uses only static files.

In my App.js, I defined this simple function:

```
const getBasename = path => path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Which I use to define the basename:

```
<Router basename={getBasename(window.location.pathname)}>
```

This works with no subfolder as well as many subfolders and it can manage reloads as well.

Comment: what is the value of the homepage in package.json?

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if your sub-routes are only 1 level deep? Seems like you couldn't do something like '/app-root-dir/users/myname' since it'd make '/app-root-dir/users' the base route.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do something similar recently in order to get a react app running in a sub directory. Try the below and see how you get on.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, useRouterHistory  } from 'react-router';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import VensaDashboard from './components/VensaDashboard';
import Inbox from './components/Inbox';
import Todo from './components/Todo';
import Home from './components/Home';

// specify basename below if running in a subdirectory or set as "/" if app runs in root
const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: "/vensa"
});

export default (
  <Router history={appHistory} />
    <Route path="/" component={VensaDashboard}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="/message" component={Inbox} />
      <Route path="/todo/:todoPage" component={Todo} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

You may also have to update the path to your bundle.js file in index.html as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vensa Development Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vensa-dashboard.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use an environment variable to adjust all your links manually.

```
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'local'; //development
const config = {
    publicPath: ENV !== 'production' ? '/' : '/dev/'
};
plugins: ([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV),
            'process.env.config': JSON.stringify(config)
        })
})
```

Then one of your routes:

```
<Route path={process.env.config.publicPath + "account/"} component={Account} />
```

Then your links:

```
<Link class="panel-close" href={process.env.config.publicPath + "account/"} >Account</Link>
```

This worked great for me. Especially since I'm using preact, whose preact-router doesn't really support the basename at this time.

```
<Router history={browserHistory} basename={'foobar'}>
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
```

Comment: Be sure to check out the solution below that uses the `<base>` html tag. It is cleaner than putting environment variables across your code base.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to install in a sub-directory then you need to specify the basename here is an example.

```
  <Router basename="/dashboard/">

  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) to generate your final `index.html` with the correct bundle names automatically injected into it.

Then set [output.publicPath](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) in your webpack config to tell webpack the subdirectory your assets will be deployed to:

```
output: {
  path: 'build',
  publicPath: "/vensa/",
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
```

Comment: This looks great in how it auto generates an HTML file with the correct prefixed path. Do I need to change the routes as well though? I'm getting `[Error] Warning: [react-router] Location "/vensa/" did not match any routes`

Comment: Yes I believe when you create the History object for your router, there's a basepath option you can pass `/vensa` and then router should work.

Comment: Yes I see https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#customize-your-history-further but not sure how to use it with browserHistory that I'm currently using. Do you know @Brandon ?

Comment: Don't use the pre-created `browserHistory`.  Instead create your own by calling `createHistory` yourself like the first example here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#examples  Use that `history` object you create instead of `browserHistory`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to trenthogan's reply, we can assign **basename to location.pathname**

```
const loc = window.location || {};
<Router history={browserHistory} basename={loc.pathname || 'foobar'}>
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
```

With this change, the app will work even if the subdirectory path changes in the future.

Comment: This actually doesn't work when you go directly to a subpage of your app, as that subpage will be assumed to be the main page and all links will be relative to /home/subpage, even though your files are at /home/js.js for example

Comment: @Larzan: Yes Larzan you are right when we directly go to subpage its a problem, the subpage now renders the main page content. But the file links issue doesn't come here, it comes only when we repeat this behaviour one more time. Have create a [demo](https://beautiful-libra.glitch.me/subdomain) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @trenthogan, that is awesome. But as novice I was stumped as where to actually put the code as I was working from a tutorial w/out ROUTER. Here's what worked for me once I got it all sussed out...

in my index.js...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router basename={'foobar'}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Which previously looked like...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: why are you unregistering service worker ? this would revoke notification permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sourcePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js');
var buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'vensa');

module.exports = {
    entry: [sourcePath],
    output: {
        path: buildPath,
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
        hash: true
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit please? It looks like entry is the same in my config `'./src/index.js'` and that the path it will build into is `vensa`. What's happening with the filename and hash? Thanks @krotov

Comment: Sorry, I'm using `[name]` as I use different entry points.
`[hash] is replaced by the hash of the compilation.`
You can see check more about webpack config [here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration)

 @magician11