# How to bundle a React app to work in ANY subdirectory on a server?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396427/how-to-bundle-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-on-a-server) explains how to bundle a react app for deployment to a specific subdirectory on a web server. I would like to bundle my react app to work on **any** subdirectory on my webserver. In other words: Is it possible to build a react app, such that I can move it from

http://server/foo

to

http://server/bar

or

http://server/foo/bar

without rebuilding or changing anything?

Answer (score 2):

in package.json

```
"homepage": ".",
```

Comment: Please describe why we need to add the same.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you're using client-side routing, unfortunately.

Comment: @Andrew have you tried "homepage": "./", ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-router-dom, If you know your directory name you could set basename to "/directory-name" in the router

or

If you want to set the base name to be dynamic, use

(Note: This won't be useful if you are using sub routing)

or

Incase of sub routing, set a standard string to your routes

Example:

```
 let basename_path = null;
   var url = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();
   if(url.indexOf("react") === -1){    // If string(react) not available
            basename_path = "/";
   }
    else{
       var array = url.split("react");
       basename_path = array[0]+"react/";
     }


 <Router basename={basename_path}>   
   <Route exact path="/react/home" component={home}/>
   <Route exact path="/react/contactus" component={contactus}/>
   <Route exact path="/react/aboutus" component={aboutus}/>               
 </Router>
```

Comment: How is the production app version built in your example when using CRA (create React app), using `"homepage": "."`? If I'm not mistaken, then the original question was asking for not having to build the production app for a specific path.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to this and similar questions seem to neglect that, if using client-side routing (like React Router) there are some back-end changes that should be made when serving from a subdirectory.

There are several approaches to this. One is to use `<HashRouter>`; that approach is described well [here](https://muffinman.io/react-router-subfolder-on-server/), or in the React Router docs.

Another approach is to use `<BrowserRouter>` with Express. Here are the steps for that:

In your app:

```js
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <Route path="/your_route">
          ...
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/">
          ...
        </Route>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Then, in `package.json`, add:

```
homepage: "https://example.com/mySubdirectory"
```

*(Note that "." will not work, if you're using client-side routing.)*

Then, in Express, try the `connect-history-api-fallback` package (which is recommended in the Vue Router docs).

```js
const express = require('express');
const historyFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

const app = express();
app.use(historyFallback);
```

Without this, users will not be able to directly enter `https://example.com/mySubdirectory/my_route` in the browser's url bar; they'll get a `cannot GET` error.

You can see an example of the above with Apache [here](https://muffinman.io/react-router-subfolder-on-server/).