# Reactjs app content doesn't display in cpanel

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-native

I have created an single page app in react js. I run it in localhost it displays content, but when i upload it in cpanel,  the content doesn't display. i think problem is in app.js file. The data for content is comming from .js components in react. The app is made just from front-end.

[cpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeFx9.png)

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSHIe.png)
[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYITr.png)

Comment: Are there any errors on the developer console? Where is the data for the content coming from? If they are coming from an API, is the API call succeeding?

Comment: (http://besnik.recufe.com/appcibo/)

Comment: i think is problem in app.js code

Comment: I just noticed you are hosting the application in a subdirectory on the server. That could be the problem. If you read the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396427/how-to-bundle-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-on-a-server you should be able to solve this.