# Deploy Expo React Native Web app to a subfolder

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web, expo-web

How can I have my mobile app also work when deployed to a web server in a subfolder?

I'm trying to create a universal app (native devices and web) using **Expo** and its `create-expo-app` boilerplate, which uses **React Native** and **React Native for Web**.

When I deploy to my web server, it will not be in the root, rather in a subfolder. When I build (`npx expo build:web`), upload to my server, and browse to `https://<myserver>/subfolder` I get a message *This screen doesn't exist*. There is a link to *Go to home screen!* which changes the browser URL, removing *subfolder*. The app functions correctly, but the URL does not include *subfolder*. Thus, this is a routing/linking issue.

I've added a property to my package.json:

```
  "homepage": "/subfolder",
```

I have seen [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396427/how-to-bundle-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-on-a-server) that `<Router>` or `<BrowserRouter>` can be given an attribute like `basename={'subfolder'}`, but with Expo and React Native there is no Router/BrowserRouter component. The boilerplate seems to use a completely different paradigm with `NavigationContainer` from `@react-navigation/native`.

**Edit:** An easy way to reproduce this is to run `create-expo-app`, then set `homepage` to `/web-build/` in `package.json`. Run `npx expo export:web` which populates the web-build folder, then run `npx serve` or `py -m http.server` or some other lightweight web server in the current folder. Browsing to `http://localhost:port/web-build/` yields the behavior I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a two-part solution, but I still don't know if this is the canonical way it should be done.

First, in `package.json` change the `homepage` property to just a dot (i.e. `"homepage": "."`). This makes file references relative to the current directory. I've seen some people argue against doing this, but it seems to work.

Second, where your screens are defined use a variable for the root path. For example:

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

var baseURL = '';
if (Platform.OS == 'web') baseURL = '/subfolder';

const linking: LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
  prefixes: [Linking.createURL('/')],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Root: {
        path: baseURL, // <- This line was added
        screens: {
          TabOne: {
            screens: {
              TabOneScreen: 'one',
            },
          },
          TabTwo: {
            screens: {
              TabTwoScreen: 'two',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      Modal: 'modal',
      NotFound: '*',
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: 2024

See: https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/#hosting-with-sub-paths

In SDK 50 and above
You can configure the prefix for static assets by setting the experiments.baseUrl field in your app config:

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "experiments": {
      "baseUrl": "/my-root"
    }
  }
}
```