# How to configure React app to run on subpath?

Tags: reactjs, express, vite

I recently got the task to configure my React app so that it will run (after build) on a Node.js server subpath `/reactapp` rather than the server root

Express is configured like this:

```js
app.use("/reactapp", express.static("public"));
```

So the production build of the React app lies in the `public` subfolder of the server and should use the `/reactapp` subpath

In order to achieve that, originally I only set the `"homepage": "/reactapp"` property in the project's `package.json` before running `npm run build`, which didn't work

After that, I found out that there are several (potential) settings I need to take care of:

- `<base href="/reactapp/">` in the `index.html`
- Change additional `<link>` elements to relative paths
- Setting environment variable `PUBLIC_URL=/reactapp` before running the build

None of that fully worked. Now I see the React app coming up (partially) but in the console I still see errors referring to the server root.

I do not use any router, so I guess basename configuration is not necessary.

[How to bundle a React app to a subdirectory on a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396427/how-to-bundle-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-on-a-server) didn't help. The `"homepage"` setting in `package.json` seems to work only if I used Create React App in the first place, but my app has been created using Vite.

After building the bundle, I can see this in the `index.html`:

```html
  <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">
  <title>Vite + React</title>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-BPgokE0a.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-DiwrgTda.css">
```

and the console errors are exactly pointing to this fact:

```
The resource on "http://localhost:6789/assets/index-BPgokE0a.js" was blocked due to a MIME type conflict
The resource on "http://localhost:6789/assets/index-DiwrgTda.css" was blocked due to a MIME type conflict
```

It is missing the `/reactapp` subpath, even though I configured it using the `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable.

After doing these changes *manually* in the production build, everything started working

1. Removed the `<base>` element from `index.html`
2. Put a `.` in front of the `/assets` links in `index.html`
3. Put a `.` in front of every absolute path reference in the bundled and minimized `index-XXXXXXX.js`

But this is not what I expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bundle a React app to a subdirectory on a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396427/how-to-bundle-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-on-a-server)

Comment: If not please expand on _"didn't work"_ and _"errors referring to the server root"_.

Comment: No, it didn't. Please refer to my latest edit

Answer (score 0):

The central point was that I was using Vite rather than Create React App, and (almost) all the tutorials, blogs and docs I found were only suitable for the latter

The solution was, in `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/reactapp",
});
```

No `homepage` setting in package.json, no `<base>` tag and no `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable were necessary.